# How to add a CentOS repo, having URL of Packages

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, rpm, repository

In Centos 7, I want to install some packages that I see in the following [URL](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/extras/x86_64/Packages/):
`http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/extras/x86_64/Packages/`

How can I add this URL to my `yum` package manager ?

PS: downloading a single rpm file doesn't work, because it looks recursively for dependencies with the same version.

Comment: That repo is already in the base set of repos for CentOS 7.

Comment: With version 7, not with a specific version `7.4.1708`

Comment: Why do you want to pin the repo to a specific version?

Comment: I want a specific package version that exists only in this repo version.

Comment: Force the releasever and then pin the package.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams can you give an example please ?

Comment: That's an entirely different question than the one in the question title or body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to add a new repo file: e.g.  `/etc/yum.repos.d/myrepo.repo` with repo configuration:

```
[myrepo]
name=My extras packages for CentOS 7.4.1708
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/extras/x86_64/
enabled=1
```

Then, to install for example `docker-1.12.6-55.gitc4618fb.el7.centos` run:

```
$ sudo yum install -y docker-1.12.6-55.gitc4618fb.el7.centos
```

Options `--disablerepo=*` with `--enablerepo=myrepo` can be used to enforce only the new repo file to be considered.

**--- UPDATE ---**

Package version 7.4.1708 doesn't exist anymore in `mirror.centos.org`. You should rather use: `baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/extras/x86_64/`

Comment: I was trying to install lftp.  I found that the name of the repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d and the name within brackets in the file does not matter.  Then all I needed to install lftp was to run `sudo yum install lftp`.

Answer (score 14):

Yum utils is a package which provides `yum-config-manager`. A quick and easy way to add a repo without the hassle writing a repo file and enabling is to use this as a sudo user

`yum-config-manager --add-repo=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/extras/x86_64/`

This will create the file and enable it for you.

P.S. [Guide](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-yum-package-management-with-yum-utils/) to install yum-utils if you don't have it already. It's part of the base CentOS repo. Usually on most yum systems, yum-utils is a must have!

Answer (score 2):

In newer CentOS versions using `dnf` basically symlinked to yum, you can add a repository with the `config-manager` command from a `.repo` file in you home directory (or any other place you can place it in):

```
sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo /path/to/my.repo
```

or

```
sudo yum config-manager --add-repo /path/to/my.repo
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at the files `/etc/yum.conf` and the ones in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, you should be able to cobble up something for unofficial repositories. That if they don't publish a package containing the required configuration.

You certainly can also download all needed packages, and install them "by hand" with yum. But that way you won't get updates automatically.

Comment: Since this is an official repository, that seems unnecessary.

Comment: The question was about *unofficial* repositories...

Comment: It was? Are we looking at the same question? The one I am looking at, right above this answer, refers to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/extras/x86_64/Packages/

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one time install of packages from this repo then you can instruct yum to include an additional repo like so:

```
yum --nogpgcheck --repofrompath=centos,http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/extras/x86_64/ install package1
```

NOTE: `--nogpgcheck` is required if you haven't imported gpg key for the repo.